# store value in cache - spring

Tags: java, spring, caching, ehcache

I am working on spring application. I have to get the String value from database and store in cache so that entire day it uses the same object without hitting the database.Below is the sample code.

ehcache.xml

```
<cache name="attPriorityCache" maxElementsInMemory="6000"
    eternal="true" overflowToDisk="false" />
```

java class:

```
import net.sf.ehcache.Cache;
import net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager;
import net.sf.ehcache.Element;
//imports here..
    class StoreData{

      @Inject
        private MyDAO myDAO;
        private static CacheManager singletonManager = null;

        private static CacheManager getInstance()
        {
            if (singletonManager == null)
            {
                singletonManager = CacheManager.create();
            }
            return singletonManager;
        }

       private Cache getCache()
        {
             //create a cache object
        }

      @PostConstruct
        public void loadData()
        {

    //get the data from database and store in cache
      final String attPriority = myDAO.getAttenderPriority(); //hits the database and get the value
     //store in cache

     if(!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(attPriority)){
                 //get the cache and remove using removeAll(), so that if value is changed in database it reflects

            }
        }
```

As i am new to this concept, please suggest how can i create the cache object for my above code and how can i preserve string value(attPriority) in cache so that it stays in cache for one whole day.
In `getCache()` method how can i create a cache object and use that in `loadData()` method to hold the attPriority value which is a string. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: You may want to have a look in the documentation first: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html

Comment: this helped me a lot:
look here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/47141/why-does-caching-of-string-objects-perform-faster